# Chain effects with dependency on the result of other effects

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a store with `bag` and `favorites`. Currently there is an action to `REMOVE_FROM_BAG`. This triggers a side effect to remove the item from your bag from the API which dispatches `REMOVE_FROM_BAG_COMPLETE` that actually removes it from the store.

We are adding an action, `MOVE_FROM_BAG_TO_FAVORITES` that will remove an item from `bag` and put it in `favorites`. If the remove API call fails, then nothing else should continue. The overall flow would be:

```
MOVE_BAG_TO_FAVORITES
REMOVE_FROM_BAG
@Effect Api Call
REMOVE_FROM_BAG_COMPLETE
ADD_TO_FAVORITES
```

Thus if the Api call fails, the item shouldn't be removed from the bag store or added to your favorites list.

```
// REMOVE_FROM_BAG side effect; API call; success removes item from the store
@Effect()
removeFromBag = this.actions$
  .ofType(REMOVE_FROM_BAG)
  .switchMap(({ payload }) => this.bagService.remove(payload)
    .map(() => ({ type: REMOVE_FROM_BAG_COMPLETE, payload })
    .catch(() => of({type: REMOVE_FROM_BAG_FAIL }))
  );
```

As for moving the item to favorites, I can it trigger `REMOVE_FROM_BAG` as a side effect as well, but I'm not sure how to make sure if the side effect succeeded or not (i.e. chain it).

```
@Effect()
moveFromBagToFavorites = this.actions$
  .ofType(MOVE_FROM_BAG_TO_FAVORITES)
  .mergeMap(({ payload }) => [
    { type: REMOVE_FROM_BAG, payload },
    { type: ADD_TO_FAVORITES, payload },
  ]);
```

In theory this should work, but I'm not sure how to prevent `ADD_TO_FAVORITES` from being dispatched in case `REMOVE_FROM_BAG` fails because the API call has failed. Is there a better way to chain actions that have side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The impure effect calls are more likely to fail than your pure reduce calls.

So I would have your effect call to be executed first:

```
@Effect Api Call -- Effect
API_CALL_COMPLETE -- Redux (should change state)
  MOVE_BAG_TO_FAVORITES -- Redux
  REMOVE_FROM_BAG -- Redux
  REMOVE_FROM_BAG_COMPLETE -- Not necessary anymore
  ADD_TO_FAVORITES -- Redux
```

If the API call fails, no rollback is necessary.

Comment: This would work okay, but then I would have to create two separate actions to dispatch to call the remove API. I am trying to avoid this and use the existing remove effect to call the API so it's only done in one spot.

Comment: If the two calls are the same, but have different effects, I would create two effect actions from it with different type IDs. yes it is duplicated, but its called from different contexts, with different side effects.  i think its definitely clearer.